# Powershell ConvertTo-Json keys in lowercase

Tags: json, powershell, lowercase

Running this code

```
get-service | Select-Object -Property displayname, status, name | convertTo-Json
```

results for instance in an output like this:

```
{
    "DisplayName":  "Adobe Acrobat Update Service",
    "Status":  4,
    "Name":  "AdobeARMservice"
},
{
    "DisplayName":  "Adobe Flash Player Update Service",
    "Status":  1,
    "Name":  "AdobeFlashPlayerUpdateSvc"
},
```

Is it possible to return the keys in lowercase?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use calculated properties:

```
get-service | Select-Object -Property @{n='displayname';e={$_.displayname.tolower()}}, status, name | convertTo-Json
```

what this does is changes the way output is formatted

ps. you could repeat that with all properties
pps. https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/josebda/2014/04/19/powershell-tips-for-building-objects-with-custom-properties-and-special-formatting/

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to keep the values like they are(only format the keys to lowercase)? With your approach both, keys and values, are formatted to lowercase.

Comment: just remove `.tolower()` from the expression. `@{n='displayname';e={$_.displayname}}`

Answer (score 2):

You can use Regular Expressions to solve the requirement:

```
#Create a variable with the info
$json = Get-Service | Select-Object -Property displayname, status, name | convertTo-Json
#Use RegEx
[regex]::Replace(
    $json,
    '(?<=")(\w+)(?=":)',
    {$args[0].Groups[1].Value.ToLower()}
)
```

And the output is like this:

```
[
    {
        "displayname":  "Application Identity",
        "status":  1,
        "name":  "AppIDSvc"
    },
    {
        "displayname":  "Application Information",
        "status":  4,
        "name":  "Appinfo"
    },
```

Comment: seems like a bash way of doing things, aka suboptimal

Comment: This may be very bash like but handles all json keys even ones not planned for.